# mysql function which return first 'X' percentile result of table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a mysql function which return first 'X' percentile of table.. I tried as given below and getting error..

any idea / suggestions pls..

```
create function precent_return (
    table_name varchar(50),
    percentiles float
) returns int
return (count(*)*percentiles/100 from table_name)
```

Comment: What did google throw up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
create function precent_return (
    in_table_name varchar(50),
    in_percentiles float
) returns int
begin
    set @retval = -1;
    set @sql = 'select count(*) * @percentiles/100 into @retval from @table_name';
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@percentiles', in_percentiles);
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@table_name', in_table_name);

    prepare stmt from @sql;

    execute stmt;

    deallocate prepare stmt;

    return(@retval);
end;
```